# zone.js throwing 404 error after upgrade angular 6 to 7.2

Tags: angular, angular7, zone.js

I upgraded my angular project from 6 to 7.2 , after that zone.js is throwing  404 for
http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1656689468665.

error: "Not Found"
message: "No message available"
path: "/sockjs-node/info"
status: 404

Comment: What happens when you execute `ng serve --public-host=http://localhost:4200` ?

Comment: same error is coming again.. @DavidR